# Could Not find Variable FieldValue, React Native/Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Trying to remove an item from the firebase array using arrayRemove but I'm getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FieldValue
```

```
    const removeItemHandler = () => {
        //this logs the array item like is should, dont think this value is the issue
        console.log(props.item)
        console.log(props.currentNote)

        //removes note from the notes array
        db.collection('users').doc(userEmail)
            .collection('books').doc(props.currentBook)
            .collection('specific').doc(props.currentNote).update({
                notes: FieldValue.arrayRemove(props.item)
            })
        showRemoveButton(false)

    }
```

I was following the example linked below, really not sure why my, very similar situation is giving me this error. Thank you!

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html

also, keep in mind that props.item is referencing the array items name, I checked the type and the value with the console.log's and it is correct. Confident that is not part of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `FieldValue` which is undefined. You cannot access it directly.
You can access it via `firebase.firestore.FieldValue` or if you imported firestore directly then `firestore.FieldValue`. So change your code like this :

```
    const removeItemHandler = () => {
        //this logs the array item like is should, dont think this value is the issue
        console.log(props.item)
        console.log(props.currentNote)

        //removes note from the notes array
        db.collection('users').doc(userEmail)
            .collection('books').doc(props.currentBook)
            .collection('specific').doc(props.currentNote).update({
                notes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(props.item)
                notes: firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(props.item) // or if you are imported firestore
            })
        showRemoveButton(false)

    }
```